# Don't show long menu title

Tags: html, css

I have a html and css but don't work in firefox ie,work only chrome.
Don't show long menu(MENU_LONGGGGGGGG) if container a menu.Show only

http://jsbin.com/isitij/1/edit

Please help me fix issue.

Comment: dont put anything and I mean anything before a DOCTYPE, not even a comment. Possibility of docs rendering in quirk modes.

Comment: remove css width from .genres class, and you can place your menu in a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: block` to `.genres li a span`.